# Stream webcam from browser to RTMP server

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to stream some content from my browser's webcam implementation to a random RTMP server. I got it working to the part where it sends blobs of WEBM (VP8 i believe) encoded bits of movie to my server every 2 seconds, but the tricky part is getting it to an RTMP server from that part on.

A bit of fiddling with FFMPEG showed that it can successfully stream to the server I want to stream to, but so far I have only managed to get it working with regular files. Attempting to stream the blobs are unsuccessful, it simply does not upload anything. It also only seems to accept mp4 encoded with the h264 codec.

*The question*: what is the best way to get the raw video data from my webbrowser's webcam implementation, encode it with the h264 codec and send it to an RTMP server?

Answer (score 3):

Without using a server to convert your blobs to an RTMP stream, The only way is you use flash. RTMP is an adobe protocol that no browsers support natively. Another option is WebRTC which uses RTP protocol.